# Is electric current just the rate of flow of charges?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, charge

I was going through the differences between Conduction and Displacement current. 
Conduction current is just the flow of electric charges but when we come to Displacement current, we see that there is no actual flow of "electric charges" rather is just the flow of electric field lines which varies with time.

I have a doubt regarding the correct definition of current. Is current the flow of electric charges or the flow of electric field lines that vary with time? Is it something else?

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current?  It explains the difference in the intro. "Displacement current density has the same units as electric current density, and it is a source of the magnetic field just as actual current is. However it is not an electric current of moving charges, but a time-varying electric field."

Comment: Displacement current is basically time-varying electric field and conduction current is flow of charges. With that in mind, what could be the general 'defination' of current?